# How can I efficiently detect all blank pages in a PDF?

Tags: pdf

My current solution is opening ["the Page Thumbnails pane on the left"](https://answers.acrobatusers.com/how-would-I-delete-all-blank-pages-at-once-in-a-document-q162915.aspx), and spotting the blank pages. What's a more efficient solution, since [this Jul 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31646450/2670739) post?

I'm not asking about deleting the blank pages automatically; I must check myself if the pages are blank before deleting.

Comment: You could speed up a manual process by displaying a grid of page thumbnails, say a 5 high x 10 wide grid, so you could see 50 pages at a time.  It would take just seconds to screen them, and delete blanks.

Comment: @fixer1234 Thanks. I updated my post to clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a start, it it quite *difficult* to determine if a page actually is blank. For example, there might be objects visible outside of the PDF box of your choice (like trimming marks), or object layers which can be switched on/off conditionally.

For a programmatic solution, you could either

- use a library like `PoDoFo` to load the PDF in question into memory, analyze each page object stream, and look for any painting commands/embedded XObjects.
- or (on MacOS) use `CGContextDrawPDFPage` (Core Graphics) to render each page - a low resolution like 72dpi should do -, and to scan for non-white pixels in the resulting image.

Comment: Hello, you've got any ideas how 1st option could be coded? I'm now trying for a few hours but cannot find a solution to detect blank pages.

Comment: @kocica there is a sample source for text extraction you can adapt. If there is no text to extract (and no painting done in the paint stream, and no XObject referenced) in a page, it is probably empty.

Comment: I've managed to solve it [similar way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61800289/how-to-determine-pdfpage-object-emptiness/61807661#61807661). Thanks.